# Multiple Submit Modal Bootstrap in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

I have `btnAdd` button which will load partial view into bootstrap modal like this :

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('#addContainer').html(data);

        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");

        $('#addModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

and the partial view loaded like this :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "MasterBanks", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divEmp", OnSuccess = "CreateSuccess" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
}
```

and `CreateSuccess` which handle the success form :

```
function CreateSuccess(data) {
    if (data !== "success") {
        $('#addContainer').html(data);
        return;
    }
    $('#addModal').modal('hide');
    $('#addContainer').html("");

    var grid = new MvcGrid(document.querySelector('#data-table'));
    grid.reload();
}
```

The problem is when I click the button, every time I open the modal whether is success or not, or just open the modal and close again without submitting the form. Next time I submit the form, the data will be posted several times just like how many I open the modal.

If I delete the `$.getScript`, the problem does not occurred.

```
$.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js");
$.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js");
$.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.js");
$.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
$.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js");
$.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
```

Why I am using that `$.getScript`? Because remote validating just working after the form loaded. Why I am not load it in partial view? I got some warning `XMLHttpRequest Deprecated` when load it inside partial view, and after browsing some articles, this solution works for this warning but created another problem.

I have tried add some script when click the `btnAdd` before bind the data : `$('#addContainer').html("");` OR `$('#addContainer').empty();` or `$('#addModal').data('modal',null);` and some others, but none of them is working.

I tried with `unbind()` also but not working, it still return multiple submit. Look like the javascipt not unloaded when the modal closed like if I put the script inside partial view.

Comment: Just disable the button after you clicked. It will prevent multiple.

Comment: @Tomato32 I don't think you read the question clearly. Disabling button is for prevent multiple unwanted clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that `unobtrusive` can be re-parsed after loading an ajax form :

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('#addContainer').html(data);
        $('#addModal').modal('show');

        $('form').each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            $el.data('validator', null);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($el);
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, For some reason the Button click is being rebind when opening the modal. Are you also loading some script inside the partial view ?

What you can try is to unbind the click event when it fires something like

```
$('#btnAdd').unbind().click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('#addContainer').html(data);

        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js");
        $.getScript("/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");

        $('#addModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Also, you can also ignore the warning message "XMLHttpRequest Deprecated" 
if your code is working

Comment: hi there, Im trying to remove the warning message by removing the script inside partial view and put the script with `$.getScript` in parent and my modal become error like this. Where I put that unbind() script?

Comment: Yes i meant  you can replace your Click Function. I have edited in the answer

Comment: weirdly, it is still submitted multiple times http://prntscr.com/m8a0or